# Give user message if filtered record not found

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have a listbox with some values. In the listbox's DblClick event I have the following code:

```
Me.Recordset.FindFirst "ToolID=" & Me.SelectedTool
```

The code works fine. However, if the user a applies a filter, some of the tools maybe in his/her fitlered results and some may not. How would I modify this code to fire a Msgbox if the value (tool) the user double clicks is not found in the already filtered results?

Many thanks.

Comment: Checking the documentation will give you the answer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-findfirst-method-dao#:~:text=Always%20check%20the%20value%20of%20the%20NoMatch%20property%20to%20determine%20whether%20the%20Find%20operation%20has%20succeeded

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Tim. Here's what worked:

```
With Me.Recordset
   .FindFirst "ToolID=" & Me.SelectedTool
   If .NoMatch Then
     MsgBox "No match"
   End If
End With
```